# Is this a good question? - Good movies for learners

Tags: discussion, on-topic

This question seems to be getting a mixed response - [What movies are good for learners who want to improve their grammar and vocabulary?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/404/good-movies-for-learners).

So far it has 9 upvotes, and 3 votes to close.

Since we're trying to define the site  I thought it might useful to see why people think it's a good/bad question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm of split opinion myself about that question. I certainly don't want to see the site overrun by such questions. This one in particular is fine I think, since it very specifically asks about language related media, even if the answers slightly verge on the *my favorite movie is ______* type.

If ***a lot*** more of these types of questions keep popping up, we'll have to be more aggressive about regulating them and probably redraw the line somewhere. A single such question here and there which is clearly language related is acceptable, I think.

*I actually found some good movies I want to (re)watch in the answers, so the question has a positive net effect so far. :-)*

Comment: Same here. There are *some* valid "lists of x" with a (kinda) limited range of answers: Radio stations, TV stations with streaming, online dictionaries, etc. But questions dealing with pure "hey, this is great" recommendations (as much fun as they are) should be kept to an absolute minimum

Answer (score 3):

I'm a beginning German student myself, and I find these types of questions *very* useful.

They give me suggestions of what material to study next, which are vouched for by native Germans as being interesting -- as opposed to dreadfully boring "made for learners" material. :P

Answer (score 2):

“Good movies for learners” is in my opinion an absolute perfect question for this site, albeit as long as there are some restrictions on what is being asked for, which there were (and as long as the title is changed to actual make it an actual question :P). As I have recently posted in my own meta-question, for learners of German the answers to these questions are invaluable, and the mixing of native speakers and learners here creates a perfect situation for asking them. Without these sorts of questions, this site will have far less value to a large portion of its potential users.

That said, there's only so many of these basic learner questions, and duplicates should be closed ASAP. So I don't think it is reasonable to worry about being over-crowded by these sorts of questions as deceze muses.

Comment: You're right the title wasn't a question, just fixed that.